# action on a Video Tag webview, Javafx

Tags: javafx, action

I work on a javafx project. I have this code.

```
public class MoviePlayer extends Application{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);

}



@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
{

         WebView root = new WebView();
               root.getEngine().loadContent(
          "<video width='320' height='240'controls='controls'  >" +
           "<source src='file:///C:/Users/lenovo-pc/workspace/EnhanceVideoJava/Movie_0001_512kb.mp4'/>" +
                        "Your browser does not support the video tag." +
          "</video> ");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 400));
            stage.show();
}}
```

Now, I want to create an action when i click on the video. Is it possible??

Tanks